# How to mix binding (<-) and assignment (let) in one line? (in Haskell)

Tags: syntax, haskell, syntactic-sugar

This is about syntactic sugar in Haskell. A simple Haskell program:

```
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let first = head args
  print first
```

I use binding in the first line (`args <- getArgs`) and a pure assignment in the second one (`let first = ...`). Is it possible to merge them together into a readable one-liner?

I understand that I can rewrite binding “de-sugared”:

```
main = do
  first <- getArgs >>= ( return . head )
  print first
```

But is there a nicer way, without cluttering the line with (>>=) and return?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`liftM` and `head` are all very well, but let us not forget pattern matching:

```
main = do { arg:_ <- getArgs; print arg }
```

or if you like layout

```
main = do
    arg : _ <- getArgs
    print arg
```

When possible, most Haskellers prefer pattern matching over `head` and `tail`.

Answer (score 10):

Yet another possibility:

```
main = putStr . head =<< getArgs
```

Comment: Well, it's nice. I didn't think about reversed version. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

How about this?

```
import Control.Monad

main = do
   first <- liftM head getArgs
   print first
```

Comment: D'oh!  19 seconds faster than me.

Comment: Yes, this is much nicier. Thank you!

Comment: Even nicer: `main = liftM head getArgs >>= print`. :)

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to use the `ap` function (with type `Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`) like this:

```
import System
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do line <- return head `ap` getArgs
          putStrLn line
```

This has the simple advantage that if your function requires several arguments you can use `ap` between each of them and you don't need to use `liftM2`, `liftM3` etc. For a function `f::a -> b -> c -> d` you write

```
return f `ap` arg1 `ap` arg2 `ap` arg3
```

Comment: Thank you. I did'n know about `ap`.

Comment: for those with an applicative taste, `ap` = <*> and `liftM` = <$>

Answer (score 1):

How are bind and return clutter?

`main = getArgs >>= (return.head) >>= print`

or

`main = liftM head getArgs >>= print`

Comment: I usually think about return as “wrap into monad”, and (>>=) as “unwrap and substitute”. So reading the code is something like “unwrap and substitute, and wrap again, and unwrap and substitute”. So, liftM is more readable for me, because it is simply “make function monadic”. So, I like option 2.